# Parse POSTed Excel file in python

Tags: python, excel, post, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

Sorry, I am a noob when it comes to web. I am trying to send an excel file using the API gateway and process it to write to S3 using a lambda in python. I am sending the file as "application/octet-stream" and parsing after I get the event object as follows:

```
import io
import cgi
import pandas as pd
import xlrd

def read_file(event):
    c_type, c_data = parse_header(event['headers']['Content-Type'])
    encoded_file = event['body'].encode('utf-8')
    c_data['boundary'] = bytes(c_data['boundary'], "utf-8")
    parsed_body = cgi.parse_multipart(io.BytesIO(encoded_file), c_data)
    return(parsed_body)
```

this essentially should give me a io.BytesIO stream which I should be able to read as

```
df = pd.ExcelFile(list(parsed_body.values())[0][0], engine = 'xlrd')
```

the function `read_file()` will be called by the `lambda_handler` as

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    p_body = read_file(event)
    df = pd.ExcelFile(list(parsed_body.values())[0][0], engine = 'xlrd')
    # Some post processing to the df
```

I am failing at the point where pandas cannot read this `parsed_body`. I also tried the `multipart` library by that too did not give me a result.

If anyone can show me a method to parse the event body and give me a result I would be greteful.

The error that I get is

```
File "<ipython-input-264-dfd56a631cc4>", line 1, in <module>
cgi.parse_multipart(event_bytes, c_data)

File    

"/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/cgi.py",line 261, in parse_multipart
    line = fp.readline()

AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'readline'
```

Comment: Do you get an error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found an answer, use base64 encoding from cURL and pass the data to the API like this

```
curl -H 'Content-Type:application/octet-stream' --data-binary '{"file": "'"$(base64 /Path/to/file)"'"}' 'https://someAPI.com/some/path?param1=value1\&param2=value2'
```

with this the API gateway receives a json in the body with the structure `{"file": "Base64 encoded string here"}`

Once you have this body first get the base64 encoded string as

```
eventBody = base64.b64decode(json.loads(event['body'])['file'])
```

Now create an empty stream and write this decoded string into the stream. Also set the seek position to 0

```
toread=io.BytesIO()
toread.write(eventBody)
toread.seek(0)
```

Finally just pass this stream to pandas

```
df=pd.read_excel(toread, sheet_name=sn)
```

And it worked.